# Gmail App does not extend table past the width of it's contents when set to width="100%"

Tags: html, html-email

So as the title might suggest I have a problem where the cells of my table are collapsing to the width of the content within them even though the width of the table is set to 100%.

Example table:

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="first-payment-details" align="left" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; border-collapse: collapse !important; width: 100%; font-size: 12px; margin: 0;">
  <tr>
    <th style=" color: #818182; font-weight: 100; text-align: left !important;  padding: 7px; border: 1px solid #e2e2e2;" align="left" width="112">Vendor</th>
    <td style=" -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; padding: 7px; border: 1px solid #e2e2e2;">Example Vendor Name</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Some of the fields in the tables are optional so there always be empty ones.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What's inside of the `first-payment-details` table class?  And I suggest throwing all of the styling in the css file

Comment: @Mark since this is a html-email it is better to stick with inline style for better cross-client support

Comment: @Mark I use a grunt script to inline the CSS from an external stylesheet. So the CSS file is for reference only. All the styles are added inline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added `!important` to the `style="width:100%"` attribute in the table html and it all works as expected now.

Solution:

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="first-payment-details" align="left" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; border-collapse: collapse !important; width: 100% !important; font-size: 12px; margin: 0;">
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you're defining and fixing the width already in the `<th style>` tag.  I would give it a percentage so that it spaces out evenly in the table

```
...align="left" width="50%">Vendor</th>
```